# Flutter version solving failed with new flutter upgrade

Tags: flutter, versioning

I have upgraded my flutter recently, previously it was working fine with every package, but now there is one thing which is bothering me right now due to which my project is not running. This is the error happening cos of this package named [PURE_MIXPANEL](https://pub.dev/packages/pure_mixpanel#-readme-tab-).

**ERROR:**

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.3.1-dev.0.0.flutter-a0290f823c.       

Because pure_mixpanel 1.0.7 requires SDK version >=1.19.0 <=2.2.1 and no versions of pure_mi
xpanel match >1.0.7 <2.0.0, pure_mixpanel ^1.0.7 is forbidden.
So, because flutter_app depends on pure_mixpanel ^1.0.7, version solving failed.
Running "flutter packages get" in flutter_app...                         
pub get failed (1)
```

From the internet, I have followed so many things like :

- flutter upgrade
- flutter channel master followed by flutter upgrade
- flutter channel dev followed by flutter upgrade

So it upgraded my flutter successfully but it raised one problem that is the package is not at all supported but previously it was working.

Here is my `flutter doctor -v` result :

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.5.9-pre.193, on Mac OS X 10.14.4 18E226, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.5.9-pre.193 at /Users/alok/flutter
    • Framework revision 3a6acb8c25 (9 minutes ago), 2019-05-09 09:23:30 -0700
    • Engine revision 644db5a49c
    • Dart version 2.3.1 (build 2.3.1-dev.0.0 a0290f823c)


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/alok/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.0, Build version 10A255
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4
    • CocoaPods version 1.6.0

[!] Android Studio (version 3.3)
```

**PUBSPEC.YAML:**

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  pure_mixpanel: ^1.0.7
```

There is no upgraded version of `pure_mixpanel` present on the web, and it is important in my project.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check it out: [Flutter 2 upgrade - Flutter version solving failed error](https://medium.com/@pratikbutani/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b)

Answer (score 1):

Your SDK version is 2.3.1 and SDK for pure_mixpanel is `sdk: ">=1.19.0 <=2.2.1"`

Check: https://github.com/seenickcode/pure_mixpanel/blob/master/pubspec.yaml

Comment: What should I do then, from sources it has been confirmed that this package has been forbidden by the newer flutter, so degrading the version will not do any good. The package should upgrade itself.

Answer (score 0):

I fix my by adding dart sdk location to env
for Windows
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk